# Golang basic trigonometry arctan computation

Tags: math, go, trigonometry

This is a Trig 101 question.  Unfortunately, I don't remember my basic trig too well (too old :).  I need to find a formula in Golang to compute the angle in degrees given the coefficient.  As an example:

Tan(angle) = coefficient
Angle = arctan (coefficient)

Examples:
Angle = arctan(0.2) = 11.31 degrees (where coefficient = 0.2)

Angle = arctan(0.3) = 16.699 degrees (where coefficient = 0.3)

Angle = arctan(0.5) = 26.565 degrees (where coefficient = 0.5)

The URL below gives the calculator which is showing the correct values:

http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/Tan_Calculator.htm

Given these examples, how do I derive a formula written in Golang to compute the angle in degrees given the coefficient?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Bharat

Comment: The math package has functions for calculating trigonometric values: https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Atan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MxjMpIbV1l)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Tan: ", math.Tan(90))
    fmt.Println("Arctan: ", math.Atan(0.2))
    fmt.Println("Arctan: ", math.Atan(0.3))
    fmt.Println("Arctan: ", math.Atan(0.5))
}
```

[List of func in math package](https://golang.org/pkg/math/)

Comment: You have to multiply the math.Atan(...) results by 180 / math.Pi to convert it to degrees though.